# EKF Slam problem with how to calculate Landmarks with Laser Data

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

recently, I've been working on EKF SLAM problem on ROS using python, but I have some questions about the laser data usages.

Since my main matrix X is represented like X= [ x  y  theta  x1  y1  x2  y2  ..........  xN   yN  ] '

where x and y are robot's estimated pose, theta is orientation and  x1, y1 represents the coordinates of first landmarks, while xN and yN represent coordinates of the N'th landmark.

But I'm not sure how to add these landmarks, because, with LaserData I have approx 200 + spots that Laser registers as an obstacle, so I'm not sure how to register it using only one x, y coordinate, but if I register every object with 200 or more landmarks, I will get insanely huge matrixes which will again, not be desirable or easy to calculate.

I've attached photo of my simulation so you can see what I mean.
http://i66.tinypic.com/dlrvoo.png

Is there a way where I could for instance just define one wall with 1 meter as a landmark and somehow place it as a one x, y coordinate, but so that my robot recognizes entire line of wall as a landmark when it scans it.

TLDR; not sure how to represent landmarks in a simple way, when my laser data scans them in 200+ spots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247381/ekf-slam-problem-with-how-to-calculate-landmarks-with-laser-data/) by [AkaTomo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/28379/akatomo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to extract features from LIDAR data to be able to run feature-based EKF SLAM. [FLIRTlib](http://openslam.org/flirtlib.html) and [FalkoLib](http://openslam.org/falkolib.html) look like they could be useful for that.

Turns out there is even a catkinized version of flirtlib_ros available in Clearpath Robotics' [flirtlib_ros fork](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/flirtlib_ros).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AkaTomo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/28379/akatomo93/) on 2016-11-06**:
I'm still not sure how, will this help me in initializing new landmarks in matrixes. Could you please try to explain it to me in more detail? Thank you in advance

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-11-07**:
Sorry, I can't look into too much detail into this, but this might help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379777/issue-calculating-landmark-covariances-in-ekf-slam. Especially the this link in the comments: http://pastebin.com/m0SHQCqg

**Comment by [AkaTomo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/28379/akatomo93/) on 2016-11-07**:
Thank you for your help. I'll look into that :)